# SSIS Package issue after upgrading from 2008 to 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssis, ssis-2017

I had a requirement to upgrade SQL server client from 2008 R2 to SQL server 2017. Previously i used SSIS packages build with SQL server 2008 R2, while upgrading the server i am facing connectivity issue when calling the package from asp.net application.

steps undertaken in upgrading the package to work with SQL server 2017.

1. I have opened the package solution file in SSDT 2017 and upgraded it to latest version.
2. I have changed the native client OLEDB provider to “SQLNCLI11.1” in the connection string.
3. Also i have added the below mentioned assembly packages in application “web.config”

   ```
   <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
   <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
   ```

I are getting the following error when tried to call the package from asp.net application.

> Failure The component metadata for "Date and Rec Count Setter, clsid {33D831DE-5DCF-48F0-B431-4D327B9E785D}" could not be upgraded to the newer version of the component. The PerformUpgrade method failed.

Comment: You may want to add more specific details to the question.

Comment: It looks like the error you are getting relates to the upgrading of your package, not running it from a .NET application.

Comment: Thanks chris for your comments. pls check my question now.i have given more details of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to configure the "Target Server Version" in the SSIS Project Properties.

You should be able to access that in Visual Studio.

If your SSIS Project is from an earlier platform and VS is trying to open as if it is from a later version of SQL Server then you may have unexpected results.

What version are you targeting? ** VS 2017 **

*UPDATE*
If the error is happening on the computer that is hosting the ASP.NET application then perhaps you should check the version of the SQL Native Client on that machine -- that might need an upgrade, assuming that it is not hosted on the SQL server.

Comment: Glenn we are targeting VS2017 .